# Dojo 1.10 and XHR: progress callback not called

Tags: javascript, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I am uploading files to server using Dojo 1.10. For the upload I use module dojo/request/xhr and trying to display progress in percents. I am confused that the progress callback is fired just one and only at the end of the transfer. The file is transferred successfully. See fragment of my code:

```
function uploadFile(){
  require([
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/request/xhr'
  ], function(dom, xhr) {
    //... some unimportant code here
    // Upload file now:
    xhr(targetURL, {
    handleAs: 'text',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': getAuthToken(), 'accept-charset': 'UTF-8'},
    data: formData
    }).then(function(data){
      // Success => refresh file list
      refreshDocList();
    }, function(err){
      // Failed
      uploadFailed(err);
    }, function(evt){
      // Progress of upload
      console.log(evt);
      dom.byId('progress').innerHTML = 'Done ' + (evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total) + '%'; 
    });
  });
}
```

I tested it in FireFox (45.0.1, Windows 8.1), Chrome (49.0.2623.110 m, Windows 8.1), MSIE (11.0.9600.18231, Windows 8.1), FireFox (44.0, Ubuntu 15.04), Chrome (48.0.2564.116, Ubuntu 15.04). In none of the mentioned browsers the progress callback is called as expected. Any tip how to solve my problem?

Comment: how big is the file you upload ? could it be that the progress event does not have time to be fired ? Dojo code for handeling this is there: https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/request/xhr.js#L141 , if you use a source version of dojo, you can try adding debug info there

Comment: I've tested it with small files as well as with big files (over 50MB). Same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's any way of doing this in dojo/request. You'll need to use XMLHttpRequest directly.

The reason is that progress events are only emitted for the download portion. For the upload portion, you need to use the **upload** member of the XHR object as follows:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
oReq.upload.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
oReq.upload.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
oReq.upload.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

oReq.open();
```

Looking at the dojo/request/xhr [source code](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/request/xhr.js), I don't think there's any simple way of getting dojo/request/xhr to expose the XHR object (and by extension the **upload** member). Hence you'll probably need to use XMLHttpRequest directly.

For more, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: The code I worked on last year never got to production, and now I'm facing this problem again. I agree with you, `dojo/request` does a good job of hooking up event listeners to the 'receiving' `XMLHttpRequest` object, which handles the response from the server, but doesn't do anything with the 'upload' object that handle the upload (the request from the browser).  See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload .. I read you must attach event listeners before calling send(), but `dojo/request/xhr` does not let you do this. Did you avoid dojo in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Further to @yassam's answer, it seems there is a way to access the `xhr` object that is behind the scenes of `dojo/request`, but for some reason I can only get this to work when I pass `true` as the third argument to `request()`.. this is the `returnDeferred` argument, and if you check `dojo/request/xhr` code it has this final line:

```
return returnDeferred ? dfd : dfd.promise;
```

So, you can do this:

```
var promise = request('some_url', { .. options .. }, true); // <-- note 'true'!
if (promise.response.xhr) {
    promise.response.xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
        console.log('xhr progress: ' + e.loaded + ' of ' + e.total + ': ', e);
    });
}
```

One thing I don't understand right now, passing `false` for `returnDeferred` (or omitting it) should return `dfd` instead of `dfd.promise` from `request()`, in which case you should be able to use `dfd.promise` in exactly the same way, but I find this doesn't exist.